# Why is javascript passing non validated information

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have the following two datetimepicker functions/fields:

```
    $(function() 
    {
        $('#updateJobForm').validate();
        var startDateTime = $('#startTime');
        var endDateTime = $('#endTime');
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var orginalDate =  startDateTime.val();

        startDateTime.datetimepicker(
            {
                timeFormat: "hh:mm tt",
                minDate: ("setDate", '',new Date()),
                hourGrid: 12,
                minuteGrid: 15,
                stepMinute: 15,
                onClose: function(dateText, inst) 
                {
                    if (endDateTime.val() != '') 
                    {
                        var testStartTime = startDateTime.datetimepicker('getDate');
                        var testEndTime = endDateTime.datetimepicker('getDate');
                        if (testStartTime > testEndTime)
                        {
                            alert("The start time cannot be greater than the end time.");
                            //startDateTime.val(currentDate.format("m/d/yyyy hh:mm tt"));
                        }
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        endDateTime.val(dateText);
                    }
                },
                onSelect: function (selectedDateTime)
                    {
                        var testStartTime = startDateTime.datetimepicker('getDate');
                        var testEndTime = endDateTime.datetimepicker('getDate');
                        //if(endDateTime.val() == '')
                        //{
                            endDateTime.datetimepicker('option', 'minDate', startDateTime.datetimepicker('getDate'));
                    }
                }
            );
            endDateTime.datetimepicker(
                {
                    minDate: ("setDate", '',new Date()),
                    timeFormat: "hh:mm tt",
                    hourGrid: 12,
                    minuteGrid: 15,
                    stepMinute: 15,
                    onClose: function(dateText, inst) 
                    {
                        if (startDateTime.val() != '') 
                        {
                            //var testStartTime = startDateTime.datetimepicker('getDate');
                            var testEndTime =  endDateTime.datetimepicker('getDate');
                            //if (testEndTime < testStartTime)
                            //{
                            //alert("The end date blah blah"); // and time must be greater than the start date and time");
                            //endDateTime.val(testStartTime.format("mm/dd/yyyy hh:MM"));
                            //}
                            //else
                            endDateTime.datetimepicker('setDate', testEndTime);
                        }
                        //else 
                        {
                        //  startDateTime.val(dateText);
                        }
                    },
                    onSelect: function (selectedDateTime)
                    {
                    startDateTime.datetimepicker('option', 'maxDate', endDateTime.datetimepicker('getDate') );
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    );
    function validate_form()
    {
        var sDate= new Date(document.updateJobForm.startTime.value);
        var eDate= new Date(document.updateJobForm.endTime.value);
        if ((document. updateJobForm.startTime.value != "") && (document. updateJobForm.endTime.value != "") && (sDate < eDate))

        {
            return true;
        }

        else

        {
            alert("Please choose a start date/time that begins before the end date/time");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And a the validate_form function that is called from my submit button that looks like this:

```
<td align="right"><input name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Update" onclick="validate_form()"/></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
```

When I click the submit button (with the wrong data i.e. the start date is grater than the end date) I get the alert message telling the user to correct the times. After the user clicks ok to the alert, the form then submits the invalid data. The function looks right and the logic seems to work, but why is the form being submitted after the function returns false? To make it worse, if the data is correct, the form will not submit at all. What is going wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a return in your button

```
onclick="return validate_form()"
```

Comment: Thanks you were correct. I am new to javascript and your assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your validation function should be placed on the "onSubmit" event of the form itself and not on the "onClick" event of the submit button! That's where the return value prevents the form from submitting!